# Can QGIS get the GPS Coordinates via the 'Windows Location Provider'?

Tags: qgis

Can Quantum GIS get the GPS Coordinates via the 'Windows Location Provider' in Windows 7/8 instead of reading a virtual com port?

If not, could this be developed as a Windows-specific plugin?  (Is there a precedence for developing Windows-specific plugins?)

Answer (score 2):

QGIS can't at the moment but I suspect support would be added at some stage.

You could develop it as a plugin if you knew the API well enough.

Here is the ticket for it http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7878